# PHP: Find directory by matching a pattern

Tags: php, directory, find, match

I have a small problem: I want to show images from directory, what I successfully programmed, but just from directory which has a static name. How can I add here some filter, or something like that, when I send in variable `osc` number *31322357* **it will automatically find directory** *31322357* - Automatic Board **and show images**? Thanks.

Here is my script:

```
<?
//path to directory to scan
$osc=$_GET['osc'];
$directory="./$osc/";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob("$directory{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.png}", GLOB_BRACE); 

//print each file name
foreach($images as $image)
{
echo "<img src='$image' style='width:100px;height:auto'>";
}
?>
```

Comment: That I must send in variable full directory, it is **31322357 - Automatic Board**, and I want just 31322357, because I have in my database just identification number and no name of device, so it must autocomplete :/

Comment: So you need to create list of directories first ... example in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
   ...
   $dirs = glob("./$osc*",GLOB_ONLYDIR);
   $images = array();
   if(count($dirs))
      foreach($dirs as $dir){
         $images = array_merge($images,glob("$dir/{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.png}", GLOB_BRACE));
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a wildcard `*` in your directory name:

```
$directory = "./$osc*/";
$images = glob("$directory*.{jpg,JPG,png}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Note that this will match `31322357 - Automatic Board` and `31322357 - Other stuff`, etc. and list files from all matching directories.

Comment: This won't work. You cant use `*/*/*/*.*` to retrieve all directories of 3rd level.

Comment: Sure you can.  Why not test it instead of speaking out of your ***.